# Separating the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix with a special block structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

I have a square matrix $J \in \mathbb{C}^{2n \times 2n}$ where,

$J=\begin{pmatrix} A&B \\\bar{B} & A  \end{pmatrix}$

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and is ${\bf diagonal}$

$B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and is ${\bf symmetric}$ so its conjugate $\bar{B}= B^*$.

These properties make $J$ Hermitian.

Now I want to separate the $n$ largest eigenvalues of $J$ in a way that can be expressed as eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ matrix constructed based on $A$ and $B$. The ultimate goal is to separate the positive and negative eigenvalues of $J$ when there are exactly $n$ positive and $n$ negative eigenvalues and identify the cases when this symmetry goes away by only inspecting the $n \times n$ matrices (functions of $A$ and $B$).

I would appreciate any help with the above problem.

Comment: The same question was posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159779/separating-the-eigenvalues-of-a-hermitian-matrix-with-a-special-block-structure

Comment: Please have a look at some discussions and guidelines on cross-posting on meta, for example http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/i-found-mo-has-been-included-in-se-network-today (There are much more posts tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) which might be interesting for you.)